# Auto calculate age script only works on first row

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script that auto calculate age based on DOB, but unfortunately it only
works on the first row.. I am already using class selector in my script but still didn't solve the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".birthdate").change(function() {
    var value = $(".birthdate").val();
    var dob = new Date(value);
    var today = new Date();
    var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    if (isNaN(age)) {
      age = 0;
    } else {
      age = age;
    }
    $('.age').val(age);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control birthdate" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" name="birthdate" required="">
</div>


<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control age" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" name="age" readonly="">
</div>
```

Comment: Use `dob.getTime()-Date.now()` instead. You need that in millisecond format to perform the correct Math.

Comment: What do you mean by "but unfortunately it only works on the first row.." ? I really cant get your question.

Comment: @urvashi Yes, I loop my html using php, sql. My issue is auto calculate age is only working on the first row..

Comment: Also, `readonly=''` means `readonly='readonly'`, so you can't write to that.

Comment: @PHPglue yes, I set it to readonly so that user wont input the age field, only they fill up the date of birth..

Comment: @mojoe ,**$(".birthdate").val()** it always points to the same element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get appropriate `birthdate` and `.age` to get calculated on `change`. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".birthdate").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var dob = new Date(value);
    var today = new Date();
    var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    if (isNaN(age)) {
      age = 0;
    } else {
      age = age;
    }
    $(this).closest('.input-group').next('.input-group').find('.age').val(age);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control birthdate" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" name="birthdate" required="">
</div>


<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control age" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" name="age" readonly="">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control birthdate" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" name="birthdate" required="">
</div>


<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control age" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" name="age" readonly="">
</div>
```

**Update:** or if you want to loop through all `.birthdate` check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.calcBtn').click(function() {
    $(".birthdate").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      var dob = new Date(value);
      var today = new Date();
      var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      if (isNaN(age)) {
        age = 0;
      } else {
        age = age;
      }
      $(this).closest('.input-group').next('.input-group').find('.age').val(age);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control birthdate" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" name="birthdate" required="">
</div>


<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control age" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" name="age" readonly="">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control birthdate" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" name="birthdate" required="">
</div>


<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control age" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" name="age" readonly="">
</div>
<hr>
<input type="button" class='calcBtn' value="Calculate">
```

Answer (score 1):

> So the main problem is with

```
var value = $(".birthdate").val();
```

> As it will always point to the first element, try using -

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

> It should work..

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea.